# Finding Laplace Transform of $f(t) = \frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

> Let 
>   $$f(t) = \frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}\tag{1}$$
>   Find the Laplace Transform of $f(t)$.

**My try:** If there was a unit step function in $f(t)$, it was easy to compute the transformation but I don't know how to tackle this problem. Also definition gives us 
$$L(f(t)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2}dt\tag{2}$$ 
Is this integration solvable?

Comment: I don't think this laplace transform is possible using standard functions but we have $$\mathcal{L}\left\{\frac{\sin{(t)}}{t}\right\}=\frac\pi2-\arctan{(s)}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman I agree, thanks for that. I tried to use it maybe with $\sin(t-2) = \sin t \cos 2 - \cos t \sin 2$ but wasn't useful.

Comment: You get an exponential integral-type bit (actually two because of the sine) plus easy bit.  But of course that is just shifting the problem.

Comment: @user10354138 Could you show your answer please? So what is the complete answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine the power series expansion of $\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}$:
$$
\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k}}{(2k+1)!}
$$
with the Laplace identity
$$
\mathcal{L}\left\{t^{2k}\right\}(s)=\dfrac{(2k)!}{s^{2k+1}}
$$
to show that
$$\mathcal{L}\left\{\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}\right\}(s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)s^{2k+1}}.$$

Some close identities by means of special functions may be obtained if one notice that $\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}$ (spherical Bessel function $j_0(t)$) admits the hypergeometric series representation $-i{~}_0F_1\left(\frac{3}{2};-\frac{t^2}{4}\right)$. For the Mittag-Leffler lovers, one can also use the identity $\dfrac{\sin(t)}{t}=E_{2,2}(-t^2)$ to show that the underlying result is a Fox-Wright function, in disguise -- see, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function.

Comment: Is there any theorem for the Laplace transform of the power series?

Comment: If the series is uniformly convergent, you can interchange the series with the integral so that the aforementioned arguments fits nicely.

Comment: So we should consider the power series of the $\frac{\sin(x-2)}{x-2}$, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Power series combined with the translation property associated to the Laplace transform.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer for three reasons. 1) It does not even attempt to answer the question that was asked. 2) It presents a series solution and neglects to state that the series has an incredibly simple closed form, as seen (for instance) in my answer below. 3) It unnecessarily introduces special functions when none are necessary to fully explain the solution to the problem this question did attempt to answer.

Comment: Well. I simply add a sketch of proof just to show that the Laplace transform may be easily obtained by power series expansion. I have assumed that with my highlights, the process of obtained the solution becomes simpler. But, of course, it requires a bit of special functiona machinery.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the intended question was to compute the Laplace transform of the function
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin(t-2)}{t-2},&t>2\\1,&t=2\\0,&t<2.\end{cases}
$$
(At any rate, this question has a more interesting answer in my opinion...)

Then by change of variables from $t-2$ to $t$ we compute that
$$
Lf(s)=e^{-2s}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dt.
$$
Now we observe that
$$
\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dt=-\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin t\ dt.
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin t\ dt=\int_0^{\infty}\textrm{Im}\ e^{(i-s)t}\ dt=\textrm{Im} \frac{1}{s-i}=\textrm{Im} \frac{s+i}{s^2+1}=\frac{1}{s^2+1}.
$$
Thus, using the famous integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dt=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we obtain that
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dt=\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}s.
$$
Finally, we obtain the answer
$$
Lf(s)=e^{-2s}\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}-\tan^{-1}s\Bigr).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

$$ \frac{1}{2} i \exp(-2 w) (Ei[2 (-i + w)] - Ei[2 (i + w)]) $$

Where: $Ei(z)$ - ExpIntegralEi is defined as in [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpIntegralEi.html). (and $i$ imaginary unit).

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

As

$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t-a)dt = \int_{-a}^{\infty}e^{-s(a+\xi)}f(\xi)d\xi=e^{-as}\int_{-a}^{\infty}e^{-s\xi}f(\xi)d\xi
$$

if $f(x) = 0$ for $x < -a$ we have

$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t-a)dt =e^{-a s}F(s)
$$

Remember that the usual Laplace transform, with limits $0\le t\lt\infty$ assumes that the function to transform is $\theta (t)f(t)$ where $\theta(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: But in this case $\frac{\sin x}{x} \not = 0$ for $x\lt 2$.